# jQuery - Get all items in a multiple select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a jQuery noob and I haven't been able to find what I want in the documentation, perhaps because I do not know what to search for. I need to get ALL values of a dropdown list.

I am currently doing:

```
<select id="cars" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And to access that, my Javascript is:

```
"cars" : $('#cars').val()
```

Unfortunately, this only returns a list of SELECTED items. Is there a simple way to return the entire list?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do something like get all the values and put them in an array, you could do:

```
$("#cars option").map(function(){ return this.value }).get()
```

Comment: Someone who actually read the question! No way! haha, good job, nice one-liner

Answer (score 0):

`$('#cars option')` would return all the `<option>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

selector

```
$('#cars option')
```

will give you list of options.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the children of the div id **cars** by using `.children()`, or simply `$(#cars option)`:

```
var ary = [];
$('#cars').children().each(function () {    
    ary.push($(this).val()); //put them in array
});
```

And you can access the children with `$(this).val()`, and store them in an array